# "formnovalidate" does not work on Chrome

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, required-field

For some reason, Chrome seems to validate the required fields even when the submit button has got the attribute `formnovalidate`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/4LA9e/

```
<form>
  Required field: <input type="text" required />
  <input type="submit" formnovalidate value="do not validate" />
</form>
```

Clicking the "do not validate" button still validates the text field (tested on Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m).

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is that a bug? Any workaround?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Had Chrome 29.something before, could not reproduce with your fiddle. Now updated to same version you are using, and there I can see it happening.

Comment: Might be this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303707

Comment: Sam for me, any fix loease ?

Comment: Looks like version 31.0.1650.57 m fixes the problem

Comment: @GyumFox, Nope, I'm still getting this error. I know that `novalidate` works on the `form` element, but is `formnovalidate` even a valid attribute on the **`input`** element?

Comment: @Pacerier, I'm no longer having the issue with Chrome. Yes you may use this attribute on a submit button (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate). Eg: when implementing a cancel button, you do not need to content to be validated before submitting the form. 
If you are still experiencing the issue, feel free to update the Chromium bug (see link above) or post your question.

Comment: @GyumFox I am using this attribute on a submit button on an HTTP GET form, and I am having the issue on both Chrome and IE 11...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment on the question, this was a regression introduced in version 30 (see [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303707)), which was then fixed in Chrome 31.